# How to ignore package.json from subrepo

Tags: webpack, babeljs, package.json, babel-loader

I'm developing a core library, where different components can be cloned and attach themselves.Each component directory has a package.json file. my core is using webpack and when I run the build command it throw error like this

```
ERROR in ./src/clients/products/src/Products.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/mughees/Desktop/midgard-react/src/clients/products/src/Products.js: Unexpected token (46:17)
```

If I remove package.json from subrepo/module it compiles fine.

This is my webpack right now.

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./src/index.js"] ,
    mode: "development",
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: { presets: ["@babel/env"] }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "css-loader",
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      },
      { 
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          "file-loader",
          {
            loader: "image-webpack-loader",
            options: {
              bypassOnDebug: true,
              disable: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, './src'), 'node_modules'],
    alias: {
      store: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/store'),
    }
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
      publicPath: "/dist/",
      filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
      port: 3000,
      publicPath: "http://localhost:3000/dist/",
      historyApiFallback: true,
      hotOnly: true
  },
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()]
};
```

Comment: Did you find any solutions? I have the same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to **babel** and not **webpack**. I had it [before](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9263).

Here is a test of having sub-directory with `package.json` file which after running **webpack** it throws an error like:

```
ERROR in ./home/three-JSX-main-patterns.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /var/www/html/ir/jsfun/home/three-JSX-main-patterns.js: Unexpected token (5:27)
```

and complains about **JSX** in my case

[image: error when we have nested repository]

#### [solution](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration)

What's your use case?

- You want to programmatically create the configuration?
- You want to compile node_modules?

  > babel.config.js is for you!
- You have a static configuration that only applies to your simple single package?

  > .babelrc is for you!

In my case I had `.babelrc` like this:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
}
```

and I replaced it with `babel.config.js` like so:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);


  const presets = ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"];

  return {
    presets
  };
}
```

And it works fine.